# how do I check the validity of a String in a text file that is supposed to be in a certain format?

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a text file that I am reading input from and the input is supposed to be in a URL format (this format is just an example). The first part for the format of the URL is the scheme. The scheme consists of a string of one or more letters followed by the string "://", so "http://" is a valid scheme. There is also the path which is a string of one or more letters, digits, periods ('.') and forward slashes. So a valid URL would consist of a scheme followed immediately by a path.

This would be valid:  `http://example.com/hello/world.html`

this would be valid:   `this123://is.a/valid.url/456`
this would be invalid: `no-scheme-url.com/index.htm`

The end goal is to tell the user whether the format of the URL they put in the text file is valid or not. Heres what I have so far, please help thanks!!

```
   public class URL {
   public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);           
   System.out.println("Name of file: ");
   String inputFile = console.next();
   File file = new File(inputFile);
 Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
while(in.hasNext()) {
    list.add(in.nextLine());
    if (list.contains("://")){
    System.out.print("valid");
}else  {
   System.out.print("invalid");
}
  }
  }
   }
```

Comment: What's the list for?

Comment: Im trying to put all the URL that the user type into the txt file into an arraylist and go from there

Comment: so, If I understand correctly , you want to validate the URL only . but the xsd schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to validate a URI

```
String validationRegex = "^([a-z0-9+.-]+):(?://(?:((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)@)?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)(?::(\d*))?(/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?|(/?(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})+(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?)(?:\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?$"

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(validationRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(urlAddress);
boolean isValid = m.matches();
```

**composed as follows:**

```
^
([a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*):                                    #1 scheme
(?:
    \/\/                                        it has an authority:

    (                                       #2 authority
        (?:(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))(\3)@)?      #4 userinfo
        (?=(\[[0-9A-F:.]{2,}\]|(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\5    #5 host (loose check to allow for IPv6 addresses)
        (?::(?=(\d*))\6)?                           #6 port
    )

    (\/(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\8)?          #7 path

    |                                       it doesn't have an authority:

    (\/?(?!\/)(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\10)?      #9 path
)
(?:
    \?(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\11           #11 query string
)?
(?:
    #(?=((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))\12            #12 fragment
)?
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) constructor as a validator:

```
boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    try {
        new URL(url);
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The reason your code doesn't currently work is because you're checking [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) instead of [`String.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)). Update your loop to this:

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    list.add(line);
    if (line.contains("://")) {
        System.out.print("valid");
    } else {
        System.out.print("invalid");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use my method, replace

```
if (line.contains("://"))
```

with

```
if (isValidUrl(line))
```

Comment: Im just trying to find out if what a user put in my text file is in the format i mentioned above, Im not quite sure what that above code does, anything a bit simpler perhaps?

Comment: I switched my code to String.contiains and its working, but how do i check that the "://" is in certain spots? like the "://" is supposed to be after whatever the user wants the url name to be.

Comment: @Picklejar75, well the point of the first part of my answer (as well as @rahulroc's) is to offer more comprehensive URL validation.

Comment: Sorry Im just a beginner so I really didnt understand the first part of your code